# How to get the thumbnail image from embedded video

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hpricot

I'm using Ruby on Rails 2.3.8 and Hpricot plugin for parsing HTML.

I would like to get embedded videos thumbnails, and searching on the internet I figured out that youtube and vimeo at least uses OG (open graph) protocol, which provides meta tags that contains the video info (url, thumbnail, etc).

For example, if I had [this video](http://vimeo.com/16430948), I could read the following meta tag, using Hpricot plugin:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/101/345/101345354_200.jpg" />
```

So, using Hpricot I should be able to parse it as follows:

```
video_url = "http://vimeo.com/16430948"

video_page = Hpricot.parse(open(video_url))

element = video_page.search("//meta[@property='og:image']")
```

But I get an empty element instead.

Note: if you searched for `video_page.search("//meta")`, it will find the one I want on the list...but using the previous syntax it won't.

Could anybody tell me how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question whilst having a similar problem with Hpricot and meta data.

In the end I had to change the xpath from **//meta** to **/html/head** to get my scraping working.  Trying the same here seems to work.

```
video_page.at('/html/head/meta[@property="og:image"]')['content']
```

Returns your image's URL.